# ID inheritance – Which IDs?

Tags: permissions, users, group, setuid, uid

I'm learning UNIX file permissions / ID inheritance and would like to clarify something:

I have this list of permissions, users, groups and files:

```
-rwxr-xr-x userA  A   foo
-rw-rwsr-x userB  B   bar
```

- RealUID of userA is 100, GroupID of userA is 240
- RealUID of userB is 102, GroupID of userB is 241

I need to know what would happen if userB executes `foo`:

1. Does userB's RealUID change to userA's RealUID?
2. Does userB's EffectiveUID change to userA's EffectiveUID?

Since userB is executing a file of userA, does userB's RealUID
get saved into SavedUID, then after executing, it reverts back to normal?

Does executing file also changes userB's GroupID?

Comment: User or Group are just records in the user database, the kernel doesn't care about it. What process care, is crendentials of a process, including RealUID and EffectiveUID and other things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for starters, users don't have RealUIDs. 
Users have UIDs. Period. 
(The situation with GIDs is *a little* more complex.)

*Processes* have real UIDs and effective UIDs (and more).

Secondly, executing a file
will never change the real UID or the real GID of a process.

Thirdly, executing `foo` will not change *any* of a process's IDs,
because it does not have the setUID or the setGID bit set in its mode.

And why have you bothered to stipulate a file `bar`
that does have the setGID bit set in its mode,
when you don't ask any questions about it?

Please do some more research and [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/494464/edit) to be more coherent.